ZeroMQ connecting publisher drops sends() until the initial connect is established
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)

# import time
# time.sleep(1)

socket.send(b'123')

Uncommenting the sleep makes it work. Any ideas how to prevent ZMQ from dropping publisher messages?
